# Issue with CTE syntax

Tags: sql-server

What is the issue with below code?

```
WITH CTE2 AS
(
select 1 as id
union
select 2
),
with CTE3 AS
(
    select * from CTE2
)
select * from CTE3
```

it fails with syntax error.

Comment: Please check following SQL tutorial on [Using Multiple CTE on SQL Server](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-multiple-cte-syntax-sql-cte-example-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) with example queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need an extra `WITH` in your code.

When using multiple CTEs, you can just separate them by comma and dont need multiple `WITH`s.

```
WITH CTE2 AS
(
select 1 as id
union
select 2
),
CTE3 AS
(
    select * from CTE2
)

select * from CTE3
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for second `WITH`

```
;WITH CTE2 AS
(
  select 1 as id
  union
  select 2
), CTE3 AS
(
   select * from CTE2
)
select * 
from CTE3;
```